# Textboxes empty after grid visibility state changed

Tags: wpf, vb.net, textbox, grid

Having a bit of a problem and haven't come across an answer or any similar situations on the internet:

I have four buttons on my main form in a wpf application. Each button controls the visibility of four grids on the form. Here is a sample code for each button's click event:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
                     System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button.Click

    grid1.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
    grid2.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
    grid3.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
    grid4.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
    textbox1.Focus()

End Sub
```

Only one button has any other code and here is a sample of it:

```
Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As
              System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button.Click

    grid1.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
    grid2.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
    grid3.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
    grid4.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
    Textbox.Focus()

    If Textbox1.Text = vbNullString Then
        dblTotal = 0
    Else
        dblTotal = CDbl(Textbox1.Text)
    End If

    If dblTotal > 5 Then
        StackPanel.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
        dblOverQts = dblTotal - 5
        Textbox2.Text = CStr(dblOverQts)
        dblPrice = dblPrice * dblOverQts
        txtPrice.Text = FormatCurrency(CStr(dblPrice))
        lblInvQtsOver.Content = CStr(dblOverQts)
        lblInvPrice.Content = FormatCurrency(CStr(dblPrice))
        lblInvPrice.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
        lblInvQtsOver.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
    End If

    totalChanger()

End Sub
```

And the above code has nothing to do with the text boxes that are coming up empty after the visibility states are changed.

Grid1 and Grid2 both have textboxes that are filled in by the user before proceeding to the next grids. I am able to switch between grids once, but if I try more than once the text boxes become empty on the second visibility change. I need the user to be able to switch between grids as much as needed to make any needed changes to information.  I get no errors at all and cannot find any code that should be causing this to happen.

Here is the xaml for the main grid that loses its textbox values:

```
<Grid x:Name="grdVehInfo" Margin="247,28,12,31" Background="#00F2A1A1" UseLayoutRounding="False" Panel.ZIndex="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Label Content="Vehicle Id : " Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,30,0,0" x:Name="lblVehID" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="77" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,30,0,0" x:Name="txtVehID" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="136" CharacterCasing="Upper" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" TabIndex="8" ToolTip="Last 8 digits of Vin#" FontWeight="Bold" Background="#00000000">
                <TextBox.BindingGroup>
                    <BindingGroup/>
                </TextBox.BindingGroup>
            </TextBox>
            <Label Content="Licence Plate : " Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="268,30,0,0" x:Name="Label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="92" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="366,30,0,0" x:Name="txtLicencePlate" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" CharacterCasing="Upper" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" TabIndex="9" ToolTip="License Plate #" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Label  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
                Height="28" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Margin="544,30,0,0" 
                x:Name="lblDate" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                Width="137" 
                Content="{x:Static s:DateTime.Now}" 
                DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, StringFormat=\{0:d\}}" FontWeight="Bold" Target="{Binding}" />
            <Label Content="Make : " Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40.007,81,0,0" x:Name="lblMake" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="97.024,81,0,0" x:Name="txtMake" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="145.976" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" TabIndex="10" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Label Content="Model : " Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="268,81,0,0" x:Name="lblModel" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="330.027,83,0,0" x:Name="txtModel" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155.973" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" TabIndex="11" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Label Content="Year : " Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="544,81,0,0" x:Name="lblModelYear" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="590,81,0,0" x:Name="txtModelYear" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="80" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" TabIndex="12" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Label Content="Engine : " Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40.007,138,0,0" x:Name="lblEngine" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="104.12,138,0,0" x:Name="txtEngine" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" TabIndex="13" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Label Content="Mileage : " Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="213.007,138,0,0" x:Name="lblMileage" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="284.057,138,0,0" x:Name="txtMileage" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" TabIndex="14" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Label Content="Oil Filter : " Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="429.07,138,0,0" x:Name="lblOilFilter" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="503.173,138,0,0" x:Name="txtOilFilter" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="88.827" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" TabIndex="15" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Label Content="Qts : " Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="598,138,0,0" x:Name="lblQts" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="642.923,138,0,0" x:Name="txtQts" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="53" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" TabIndex="16" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Label Content="Brand Oil : " Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,192,0,0" x:Name="lblBrandOil" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="115,192,0,0" x:Name="cbxBrandOil" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="147" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" TabIndex="17" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Label Content="Oil Wieght : " Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="298,192,0,0" x:Name="lblOilWieght" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="384.39,192,0,0" x:Name="cbxWeightOil" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112.783" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" TabIndex="18" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Label Content="Hood Tech : " Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40.007,248,0,0" x:Name="lblHoodTech" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="123,247,0,0" x:Name="cbxHoodTech" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" TabIndex="19" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Label Content="Pit Tech : " Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="224.007,248,0,0" x:Name="lblPitTech" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="300,247,0,0" x:Name="cbxPitTech" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="62" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" TabIndex="20" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Label Content="Comments : " Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40.007,300,0,0" x:Name="lblComment" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <TextBox Height="127" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="125,300,0,0" x:Name="txtComment" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="253" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" TabIndex="21" FontWeight="Bold" />
            <Border BorderBrush="#FF8D8787" BorderThickness="0" Height="690" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" x:Name="brdVehicleInfo" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="718" CornerRadius="15" Panel.ZIndex="-1">
                <Border.Background>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFB9B7B7" Opacity="0.3"/>
                </Border.Background>
                <Border.Effect >
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="10"/>
                </Border.Effect>
                <DataGrid x:Name="dgPastServices" Margin="40,457,26,23" HeadersVisibility="Column" CanUserReorderColumns="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectedIndex=" -1">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header= "Service Date" Binding= "{Binding Path=ServiceDate}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header= "Mileage" Binding= "{Binding Path=Mileage}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="License Plate" Binding= "{Binding Path= LicensePlate}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Oil Brand" Binding= "{Binding Path= OilBrand}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Oil Weight" Binding= "{Binding Path= OilWeight}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Comments" Binding= "{Binding Path= Comments}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns> 
                    <DataGrid.BindingGroup>
                        <BindingGroup/>
                    </DataGrid.BindingGroup>
                </DataGrid>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
```

And here is the xaml for the buttons:

```
<Button BorderBrush="#6928A3A3" BorderThickness="0" Content="Vehicle Info" FontWeight="Bold" Height="57" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="32,140,0,0" x:Name="btnVehicleInfo" OpacityMask="{x:Null}" Style="{DynamicResource RoundedButton}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="168">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0E4E76" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA4CEE8" Offset="0.439" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
            <Button.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="5"/>
            </Button.Effect>
        </Button>
```

Comment: I think you will have to show us more of your code. At least some XAML. The best would be the minimum code required to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I seem to have found my problem.  It seems to be simple Lost Focus event on the first textbox of my grid2.

Comment: Is there a better way to test a users input in a textbox after it is entered then LostFocus?